# Expresso Store Reports Not Working

Tags: expresso-store

It appears that reporting is not quite working. On several of my sites I have noticed the reports barely work, crash, and/or just go back to the cp home. This is on both "view" and "pdf". I can't get the dates to really work right either. Is this a known limitation, or am I doing something wrong on my side?

Brad

Comment: Hi Brad. What version of Store and EE are you using? Also with the date selector in the CP can you confirm that there are no errors in the console?

Comment: Also which version of PHP are you using? and how many orders/items are being displayed in the reports? (perhaps it is a memory limit issue)

Comment: Hey all, the version is 1.6.3 and PHP is 5.3. I can move to 5.4. I have 64MB of memory and there is only about 30 orders.

Comment: Hey Brad. Probably best if we follow this up via email. I don't think we will be able to help much without admin access and some server logs. Will be in touch!

Comment: I am also having the same issues. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Greg - can you please email support@exp-resso.com with specific details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally the Store reports are fairly memory hungry. If you have your memory limit very low, try raising it to at least 128mb (256mb or 512mb is preferable - on todays servers memory is cheap).

Another problem people often run into with the reports page is to do with EE's secure forms feature. If you have secure forms enabled, then using the browser back button will not work correctly in your control panel. If you generate a report, then click back, then try to generate another report, you will get an error, or be redirected back to the CP home page. The best solution to this is simply to disable EE's secure forms feature under Admin > Security & Privacy > Security & Sessions > "Process form data in Secure Mode?".